# Is there a full swipe action for a NSTableView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am trying to implement a swipe to delete action on a NSTableView row, similar to the mail app. The code that I have works, but the 'threshold' to swipe fully is very high and its nearly impossible to delete the row with the gestures alone and you would need to click the delete tab that becomes visible.

Is there a way to implement full swipe gestures similar those in the mail app or even iOS table views?

My code creating the action:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableView.RowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
    // left swipe
    if edge == .trailing {
        let deleteAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
            // action code
            SafariTabList.tabList.remove(at: row)
            tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: row), withAnimation: .effectFade)
        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        return [deleteAction]
    } else if edge == .leading {
    }
    
    let blankAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
        // action code
    })
    blankAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    return [blankAction]
}
```

*Please remember this is a macOS appkit question.*

Comment: There is no such control requiring the user to swipe to my knowledge.  "I am trying to implement a swipe to delete action on a NSTableView row, similar to the mail app."  Mail has one?  Where?

Comment: The mail app, when you have an email selected, allows you to swipe on the selected email. Right to mark as unread and left to delete. This is apparent in the code I have for NSTableRowAction, as the action can be destructive.

Comment: You don't want to use `rowActionsForRow` because there are people like moi who don't use Apple Wireless Mouse.

Comment: I have been using the trackpad with the code I posted. What would be the alternative for mouse users?

Comment: Pressing the delete key after selecting a table row and selecting Delete from the menu

Comment: I did specify that in my question.. the problem is with deleting with the swipe gesture and not needing to click on the delete button. Deleting by swiping is more difficult than what some apps make it out to be